# pass item shown textbox to listbox

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

I am currently learning on Webcam based qr code decoder. I would like to request advice on passing the decoded code which is shown in a textbox to be listed out in a listbox. So, I could see the list of item which has been decoded. here is the [code](https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/AForgeDemo/AForgeDemoForm.cs) which I am currently trying to rebuild.

Here is the code which shows the decoded qr code

```
private void ShowResult(Result result)
{
   currentResult = result;
   txtBarcodeFormat.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
   txtContent.Text = result.Text;
}
```

And I added a listbox to the program to show the list of decoded code. This is an [example I saw](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/447963/passing-textbox-values-to-listbox)

```
void fill_listbox()
{

    string[] values = result.Text;

    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        if (value.Trim() == "")
            continue;
         listBox1.Items.Add(value.Trim());
    }
}
```

Any advice on what should I input to replace "= result.Text;"?

Comment: Instead of `if (value.Trim() == "")` you should use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)`

Comment: You can also try `if (value.Trim() == String.Empty)` instead of `if (value.Trim() == "")`

Comment: @Shaharyar: That's the same difference. My point was that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` does not need to create new strings unlike `Trim`.

Comment: thanks mr tim and mr shah, i would try your method.

Comment: sir, what should i input at "string[] values = ?" if i use result.Text, it would trigger "the name result does not exist in current context'. kindly advise. thank you

Comment: hai,just to share with u guys. i found another way which list it horizontally - http://pastebin.com/aF1TJUnr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the individual characters in the ListBox you can do this:

```
private void ShowResult(Result result)
{
   currentResult = result;
   txtBarcodeFormat.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
   txtContent.Text = result.Text;
   fill_listbox();
}

void fill_listbox()
{
    char[] values = txtContent.Text.Text.ToCharArray();

    foreach (char value in values)
    {
        if (value == ' ') { 
            continue;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);

    }
}
```

Alternatively you could first remove the spaces and do something like this:

```
void fill_listbox()
{
    char[] values = txtContent.Text.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToCharArray();

    foreach (char value in values)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, would be trying your method now. thanks for the help mr kenneth

Comment: sir, i tried the first method. i replaced  'result.Text.ToCharArray()'                                                  with    "txtContent.Text.ToCharArray();" . when i debug it gives a warning "unreachable code detected" . then i run it, the scanning process seems to slow down and nothing appears in the listbox. any advise on where i might have did incorrectly. thank you

Comment: the second method does not prompt a warning but still no result on the list box. kindly advise

Comment: Could you show me the complete code? You are probably not executing the code at all

Comment: ya, sure. do you have email? mine is weeleum@hotmail.com . or you can email me through the address, then i send you the coding. thanks for your help

Comment: Please just add the relevant bits to your question, like for example the call to `fill_listbox`, otherwise just paste the code on pastebin.com or something like that

Comment: alright sir, i will paste at pastebin.com. pls give sometime to upload. thank you

Comment: You're not calling the method. Please modify the ShowResult function as detailed in my edited answer

Comment: sir, there is an error. it says " the name "result' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need to access the textbox directly. Replace `result.Text` with `txtContent.Text`

Comment: yup, just replace it and its working. And thank you so much for your guidance Mr Kenneth. Thanks a million.

Comment: OK, no problem. Happy coding. Please remember to up vote / accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: one last question Mr Kenneth, to get the list box to show the item horizontally instead or in vertical form, is it just by setting at property or do i need to program it to do so. kindly advise. thank you

Comment: hai kenneth, i couldnt get the result in a horizontal manner, so i changed the a little of the coding and it give the desired result. just for sharing - http://pastebin.com/aF1TJUnr